# Trying to install package and npm throwing Err 404 error

Tags: react-native

I am tring to install cameraroll package and I keep getting this error whenever i try to install any package. I've searched on the net for reactr-native-popup-menu@^0.15.12 but cant find out what it is. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you[The 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPYke.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not install the right package the package is `react-native-popup-menu` not `reactr-native-popup-menu`. You are adding **"reactr"** you should be add `react` instead of `reactr`.

Here's the package `npm i @react-native-community/cameraroll` for camera roll that you want to install you can check for more details [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cameraroll)

Ana also you can create camera roll by using FlatList if you want to create Custom camera roll you can check it [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjC2oUJhePE)

I Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: I'm actually  trying to install cameraroll package and I'm getting that error

Comment: you can install this npm i @react-native-community/cameraroll

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution  to this error. The react-native-popup-menu was written as "reactr-native-popup-menu@^0.15.12" in package.json folder